# How to serialize a Sequel result into JSON

Tags: json, ruby, sequel

This is my Model

```
class Client < Sequel::Model(:clients)
end
```

When I execute

```
Client.first.to_json
```

I get

```
"\"#<Client:0x2594b824>\""
```

But when I execute

```
DB[:clients].first.to_json
```

I correctly get:

```
{id: 1, name: "Someone" ... }
```

What am I doing wrong?... I also tried using `Client.dataset.first.json` having the same result.

Also I'm using a MS Access DB but I don't think that's important.

Comment: Have you got this somewhere: `Sequel::Model.plugin :json_serializer`. If so, what is `Client.first.class`?

Comment: Ok, I just added it and it worked straight away, thanks a lot!

Comment: I'd try `Client.first.to_h.to_json`. A model returns an instance of that class so you need to convert the result to a hash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `json` library (part of the Ruby standard library), and other gems such as ActiveSupport, monkey patch objects with a `to_json` method which could be what is getting called, not a the specific `to_json` method supplied by Sequel which knows how to convert a `Sequel::Model` instance to JSON. This is speculation as I'd be surprised that the JSON library monkey patches anything other than `String`, `Array`, `Hash` etc.

When using `DB[:clients].first` you probably get back a `Hash` which has a `to_json` method, where as `Client.first` returns a model instance which isn't handled by the generic `to_json` method supplied by the json library.

Try registering the Sequel JSON plugin, this should take precedence over the monkey patched `to_json` method:

```
Sequel::Model.plugin :json_serializer
```

By the way this is a good indicator of why monkey patching is often a bad idea, particularly monkey patching of classes which are outside a libraries/gems namespace.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `to_hash`:

```
require 'json'
require 'sequel'

DB = Sequel.sqlite
DB.create_table :items do
  primary_key :id
  String :name
  Float :price
end
items = DB[:items]
items.insert(:name => 'abc', :price => rand * 100)

class Item < Sequel::Model(:items)
end

Item.first
  .to_hash # => {:id=>1, :name=>"abc", :price=>51.47074347440235}
  .to_json # => "{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"abc\",\"price\":51.47074347440235}"
```